# Appending some elements into list but before paragraph

Tags: jquery, append

I have structure like this.

```
<ul class="gallerylist">
<li>
    <image ...>
    <input ...>
</li>
<li>
    <image ...>
    <input ...>
</li>
<li>
    <image ...>
    <input ...>
</li>
<p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>
</ul>
```

because of visual correction i have to use `<p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>` part and i'am adding new list items dynamically via JQuery by:

```
$('ul.gallerylist').append('<li><img .../><br/><input .../></li>');
```

but as you can guess it is appended after the `<p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>` part and it corrupts the visual correction.

**My question is :** Which way is true to add li inside ul as last but before `p` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Note

I think your HTML markup is not valid, can't place `p` within `ul` like you've done. Better would be wrap the `p` within another `li` and use `CSS` to accomplish you job.

For example:

***HTML***

```
<ul class="gallerylist">
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <input type="text">
    </li>
    <!-- wrap within li and assign a class to that li-->
    <li class="makeclear">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
/* apply css to that li*/
.makeclear{
    clear:both;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$('ul.gallerylist li.makeclear')
         .before('<li><img src=""/><br/><input type="text"/></li>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/399/)**

Read about [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/), it will insert an element before the matched element by selector.

**OR**

```
$('<li><img src=""/><br/><input type="text"/></li>')
                   .insertBefore('ul.gallerylist li.makeclear');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/398/)**

Read about jQuery [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore)

***But, valid markup is necessary otherwise IE will make you mad. Comments below can give you some clues.***

Comment: if the html is invalid, why reference invalid html in your code?

Comment: @charlietfl I make note to OP, my job is not make html correct, I just show a demo and I think my html is valid now

Comment: providing code against invalid html...does that help? `insertBefore('ul.gallerylist p');` would likely fail in IE

Comment: @thecodeparadox i know, you are all right about validation but problem is that; i am using this markup in UI Accordion and list items are floated to left (like bricks) when i use clear:both in last li, appearance of listing is corrupted. I tried many things (even your suggestion), but no success. At the end, i decided to forget about validation (for this specific case) bacause code will be used as backend Admin area. Now i am striving against IE.

Comment: @Alper make the last LI display:block with no float as well and can apply jQuery UI class `ui-helper-clearfix` as well. IE hates invalid markup as was my point earlier

Answer (score 1):

`P` tag is not a valid child of `UL` so your html is invalid

You need to change your  `P` to an `LI` You can give it a different class for style purposes

Now you will be needing to insert before last `LI`

```
   $('ul.gallerylist li:last').before('<li><img .../><br/><input .../></li>');
```